# How to make the modal backdrop opacity cover the page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need to make the content in the background invisible. Meaning when the modal is shown its background is currently semi-transparent so the user can see the content of the page. I want to change that.

Thank you

Comment: answer to your query lies in your code  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.modal-backdrop{opacity:1 !important;}
```

This is an easy one :) sorry for bugging you guys